# Adding a custom data-attribute to a field in Views

Tags: views, 8, theming

In a view I need to add a custom data-attribute to the row output (just like classes are added). Simply rewriting the output doesn't work because XSS attribute filtering strips the attribute.
How can I accomplish this in a reasonable way?
These answers are for D7 and do not quite cover dynamic output:

[Custom attribute in views fields](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/106608/custom-attribute-in-views-fields)

[How to add data attributes to view list <li> tags?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/111244/how-to-add-data-attributes-to-view-list-li-tags)

Comment: How are you trying to Rewrite, with what code? I haven't noticed any stripping of the attribute, maybe it's only your value missing?

Comment: Oh man, you are right, it was a missing value! When things didn't work, I started research, found out that the style attribute is stripped in views when rewriting and stumbled upon https://www.drupal.org/project/views/issues/417956 – so I concluded, the attribute is stripped as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize for future reference:

You **can** add data attributes using Rewrite in Views Fields.

If you added a custom data-attribute but something isn't working, the problem might be in the value ;)

---

What gets stripped by the `filter_xss_admin()` on Rewrite is most notably the `<object>` tag and `style=""` attribute because users can submit malicious code through those.

It seems Views for D7 will have that check removed in the next release: [Remove filter_xss_admin() from result rewriting because views editors are already trusted admins](https://www.drupal.org/project/views/issues/2529948)